# Golang Using Type Struct List

Tags: json, go, golang-migrate

I wanna using my Struct like List but IDE cannot give a chance for using.
I know, have a syntax problem but I cannot find true syntax.

I don't where is my mistake in code.

What is the correct syntax when using Struct List ?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Student struct {
    Firstname string   `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string   `json:"lastname"`
    Email     string   `json:"email"`
    Languages []string `json:"languages"`
    Profile   []Profile
}

type Profile struct {
    Username  string            `json:"username"`
    Followers int               `json:"followers"`
    Grades    map[string]string `json:"grades"`
}

func main() {

    var John Student

    // defining struct

    John = Student{
        Firstname: "John",
        Lastname:  "Miller",
        Email:     "johnmiller@gmail.com",
        Profile: Profile{
            {
                Username:  "Miller_267",
                Followers: 1988,
                Grades:    map[string]string{"Education Level": "master", "University": ""},
            },
            {
                Username:  "John Miller",
                Followers: 1997,
                Grades:    map[string]string{"Education Level": "master", "University": "Leicsheter University"},
            },
        },
        Languages: []string{"Eng", "Esp"},
    }

    res, err := json.MarshalIndent(John, "", " ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(res), "\n", err)
}
```

In above syntax what is my mistake ?

Comment: Are we to guess what the reported syntax error is?

Comment: @jdizzle no.I just wanna know what is correct syntax when you use Struct type list

Comment: @SabuhiGurbani What he meant is, please include the error message in your question.

Comment: Even better would be a playground link

Comment: @super 
cannot use Profile{...} (type Profile) as type []Profile in field value,
missing type in composite literal,
missing type in composite literal,
too few values in Profile{...}

Comment: @jdizzle https://play.golang.org/p/e8FODN1yjRy

Comment: You’re declaring a Profile as a []Profile

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/v9Jvl-6C7lc See spec [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals).

Comment: @mkopriva That's what I trying to say.Thanks a lot.I understand what is my mistake.

Comment: Typo?  It looks like you dropped the [] in the slice type.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a slice in the literal, to match the type definition:

```
package main

import (
   "encoding/json"
   "os"
)

type profile struct {
   Followers int
   Username string
}

type student struct {
   Firstname string
   Profile []profile
}

func main() {
   john := student{
      Profile: []profile{
         {1988, "Miller_267"}, {1997, "John Miller"},
      },
   }
   json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(john)
}
```